# DPDK installation on UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, forwarding, packet

I have been given a task of installing and running DPDK on ubuntu 18.04. However, I have no idea about linux and DPDK is entirely new thing for me. Please guide me on how to install it including resolving the package dependencies and installing softwares on linux machines. Anything will be helpful.

Comment: superuser is a platform for where you can get help, but you seem not to have done anything by yourself except this "help me to do it" post, You should first research it yourself and let us know what you have done up to this point and with what you are stuck. I just googled DPDK and I would suggest start by reading this [DPDK Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/DPDK.html.en) and come back when you get stuck with specifics.... Regarding SW installs on linux, set up a VM and play around with it. A lot of guides out there...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use DPDK,

1. pre-built dpdk binary (via distro)
2. custom build from source files

For ubuntu platform, please refer [how to install DPDK with ubuntu as package](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-dpdk). Else please use [DPDK quick start guide](http://core.dpdk.org/doc/quick-start/)